# How come #define directive does not work when using an array

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define maxcommission 5000
#define commission_rate .1

main()
{
    char   employee[100][65], response[10];
    double sales[100], commission[100];
    int    i;
    for(i=0;;)
    {
        printf("Do you want to add another employee? ");
        fgets(response, 10, stdin);
        response[(strlen(response)-1)]='\0';
        if (strcmp(response[i], "no") == 0 || strcmp(response[i], "n") ==0 )
            break;

        printf("Who is the first employee? ");
        fgets(employee[i], 65, stdin);
        employee[i][(strlen(employee[i])-1)]='\0';
        printf("How much did you sell?\n");
        scanf("%lf", &sales[i]);
        fflush(stdin);
        commission[i] = (sales[i] * commission_rate) > maxcommission? 5000 : sales * commission_rate; // this line gives me an error
    }
}
```

I was just learning about the #define pre-processor directive and I wanted to test it out in a program. I've created a program that defines a few things. It works fine with just 1 employee entry, but when I try to expand it to make an array of employees, I get compiler errors.

Specifically `invalid operands to binary * (have 'double *' and 'double')`. Why does this give me an error when a single entry would work fine? How would I go about fixing this?

This is the line in question:

```
commission[i] = (sales[i] * commission_rate) > maxcommission? 5000 : sales * commission_rate; // this line gives me an error
```

Comment: You need to provide the code snippet that goes wrong as well otherwise it is hard to comprehend what you are trying to say.

Comment: `sales * commission_rate` is attempting to multiply a pointer and a double.

Comment: thanks I added it on to the bottom.

Comment: Ahh So is it correct to add (double) in front of the sales?

Comment: @Khrono no. That would multiply `commission_rate` by garbage. Instead, you need to fix the logic error.  I guess you mean `sales[i]` instead of `sales` there.

Comment: Thank you much I see what I did wrong there. Thank you @MattMcNabb and everyone else who responded.

Answer (score 2):

The line ends with `sales * commission_rate`.  I think you meant to write `sales[i] * commission_rate`.

Answer (score 1):

```
commission[i] = (sales[i] * commission_rate) > maxcommission? 5000 : sales * commission_rate; // this line gives me an error`
```

should be

```
commission[i] = (sales[i] * commission_rate) > maxcommission? 5000 : sales[i] * commission_rate; // this line gives me an error`
```

Answer (score 0):

Directive works fine with an array.

```
: sales * commission_rate;
```

You are trying to multiply a pointer (without dereferencing it) to an constant. That is the error.